# Provable well-founded ordering

Tags: logic, ordinals, proof-theory, well-orders

Quote from Sieg/Parsons commentary on Gödel's Zilsel lecture:

> ...it has to be clarified how to grasp ... specific countable ordinals
>   ... That can be archieved in the system $S_1$ with function parameters,
>   by considering definable linear orderings $\prec$ of the natural numbers
>   such that, for a definable functional $\Phi$ and for all functions $f$, $S_1$
>   proves:
>
> $$
>  \neg { f (\Phi(f) + 1) \prec f (\Phi(f)) };
>  $$
>
> i.e., $\prec$ is provably well-founded.

I don't understand why this formula expresses well-foundedness of $\prec$. Any help?

Edit: OK, I think I see the light. If $\prec$ is not well-founded, then there is an infinite decreasing sequence of its elements, hence there would be an $f$ such that for any $n$, $f(n+1) \prec f(n)$. But then there cannot be a $\Phi$ satisfying the above condition.

Comment: This seems like strange wording, if we are currently working on the $f(n+1)\prec f(n)$ case for instance (i.e. we have $\Phi(f)=n$), to transition up to the $f(n+2)\prec f(n+1)$ case we need to consider a different $f'$ in order to get $\Phi(f')=n+1$ as needed.